# How to change the color of Keyboard to dark in Swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui, keyboard

In the normal uikit I can change the keybaord color using the following

```
myTextField.keyboardAppearance = .dark
```

How can I achieve the same effect using Swiftui

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.appearance()`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITextField.appearance().keyboardAppearance = .dark
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // Code
    }
}
```